# Como hacer uso de alerts de Bootstrap (v3)

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-3, alert

Quisiera dejar de usar estos mensajes molestos tipo `alert` que genera el navegador en la parte superior y usar los alert que contiene la librería de Bootstrap, en este caso deseo utilizarlos en unos `input file` así como el ejemplo a continuación:

```html
 <form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="fileToUpload" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label"> Archivo XML:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="XmlToUpload" class="btn" accept=".xml" onchange="ValidarArchivos()" required="">
              </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                         <label for="pdfToUpload" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Archivo PDF:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input type="file" name="pdfToUpload" id="pdfToUpload" class="btn" accept=".pdf" onchange="ValidarArchivos()" required="">
              </div>
                    </div>      
              </div>

          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
            <button type="button" id="upload" class="btn btn-success" disabled="">Subir Documentos</button>
          </div>
      </form>
```

Los mensajes que me interesaría mostrar en los alert de la librería de Bootstrap son los que contengo en la siguiente función de Javascript como `alert` tradicionales del navegador

```
function ValidarArchivos(){
  
    var ValorPDF = $('#pdfToUpload').val();
    var ValorXML = $('#XmlToUpload').val();
    if(ValorPDF != "" && ValorPDF != undefined && ValorXML != "" && ValorXML != undefined ){
        var ValidarNombrePDF = document.getElementById('pdfToUpload').files[0].name;
        var ValidarNombreXML = document.getElementById('XmlToUpload').files[0].name;


        var arcPDF = ValidarNombrePDF.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/,'');
        var arcXML = ValidarNombreXML.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/,'');

        var regex = /([^-\w.]*)/gm; 

        var arcPDF2  = arcPDF.replace(regex, ''); 
        var  arcXML2  = arcXML.replace(regex, '');

        if( !(arcPDF==arcPDF2)  || !(arcXML==arcXML2)) {
            alert("Favor de validar que el nombre de los documentos no tengan espacios ni caracteres especiales.");
            $('#XmlToUpload').val('');
            $('#pdfToUpload').val('');
            return;
        }

        var NombrePDF= ValidarNombrePDF.substring(0, ValidarNombrePDF.length - 4);
        var NombreXML= ValidarNombreXML.substring(0, ValidarNombreXML.length - 4);
        if(NombrePDF == NombreXML){
            //alert("Los datos son correctos. ");
           
        }else{
            alert("Favor de validar que los documentos correspondan con el mismo nombre. ");
            $('#XmlToUpload').val('');
            $('#pdfToUpload').val('');
        }
    }
}
```

Como información adicional estoy usando la versión **3.3.7** de Bootstrap.

Espero que alguien pueda orientarme en el uso correcto de estos `alert`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Muy bien. Después de trabajar por este código, logré algo parecido a lo que estás buscando.

Primero, agregué el `div` de la alerta justo debajo de tu input:

```
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="XmlToUpload" class="btn" accept=".xml" onchange="ValidarArchivos()" required=""> 
      
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">  
 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>  
 <strong>Texto</strong> y enlace <a href="#" class="alert-link">info</a>.
</div>
```

Ahora en **CSS** agregué un nuevo estilo para este `alert`:

```
.alert {
 display: none;
}

.alert.visible {
 display: block;
}
```

Luego en el **jQuery** donde están definidas las acciones del formulario:

```
// Antes de todos
var alerta = $(".alert");

// Y donde llama la alerta
alerta.addClass("visible");
```

Y ya está! Funciona de maravilla!
Se puede editar el texto de la alerta en el HTML, y elegir varios tipos **[aquí](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/alerts/)**. Y **no es necesario** agregar otro evento en para cerrar en jQuery para la `alert` porque éste ya tiene su propio cierre: `alert-dismissible`.

Comment: Solo me queda duda en algo, veo que la documentación que me dejaste corresponde a la versión 4 de Bootstrap, funciona igual tu código ?

Comment: Y... ¿Por qué no haces una prueba? Yo hice usando tu código de pregunta y esos ```alert``` de la referencia y, funciona perfectamente. Por eso te respondí

Comment: Realice la prueba y el `alert` se muestra de entrada, no al momento de que se cumpla la validación, hay algo mas que deba cambiar en el código ?

Comment: No hay nada que cambiar ni arreglar. Simplemente agrega el ```var alerta = $(".alert");```  entre los demás **var** y reemplaza tu ```alert``` por ```alerta.addClass("visible");```, y el estilo en tu CSS y ya

Comment: Tu respuesta funciono de maravilla, solo algo adicional hay manera de que el mensaje después de mostrar se desaparezca a los 10 segundos ?

Comment: @JohnDoe revisa: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#alerts-events

Answer (score 2):

Puedes tener una sección en la parte superior del sitio para mostrar las *alertas*, que puedes ir creando a medida que las necesitas con una función como la que incluyo en el ejemplo a continuación:

```js
function agregarNuevaAlerta(clase, mensaje) {
  let alertasDiv = document.getElementById("alertas");
  
  let alerta = document.createElement("DIV");
  alerta.innerHTML = mensaje
  + '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">'
  + '<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>'
  + '</button>';
  alerta.classList.add('alert');
  alerta.classList.add(clase);
  alerta.classList.add('alert-dismissible');
  alerta.classList.add('fade');
  alerta.classList.add('show');
  alerta.setAttribute("role", "alert");

  alertasDiv.appendChild(alerta);
  $(alerta).toggleClass('in out'); 
}

function generarNuevasAlertas() {
  agregarNuevaAlerta('alert-success', '<strong>¡Éxito!</strong> todo salió bien.');
  agregarNuevaAlerta('alert-warning', '<strong>¡Advertencia!</strong> parece que algo salió mal y estoy aquí para decirtelo.');
  agregarNuevaAlerta('alert-danger', '<strong>¡Problemas!</strong> algo salió mal.');
  agregarNuevaAlerta('alert-info', '<strong>Información</strong> ni bien ni mal, tú ¿cómo estás?.');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Ejemplo</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container" id="cnt">
  <div id="alertas">
  </div>
  <div id="contenido">
    <h1>Contenido</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam</p>
    <button onclick="generarNuevasAlertas()">Generar alertas</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Puedes probarlo aquí mismo en la respuesta haciendo clic, primero en el botón *"Ejecutar"*, para ejecutar el snippet de código, y luego en el botón *"Generar alertas"*.

Al final, la función `agregarNuevaAlerta()` es la que hace el *trabajo sucio*, su código es bastante simple, así que espero que se auto-explique, pero si no, no dudes en dejar un comentario.

Comment: Tu respuesta parce estar muy completa pero puedes adaptarlo al código que agregue en mi pregunta inicial para darle una validez mas asertiva a tu respuesta

Comment: Definitivamente no lo haría, la idea es que yo te doy los bloques y tú armas el lego final. En realidad te he dado todo lo que necesitas, lo que te toca a ti es hacer 3 cambios en el código. Lamento que mi respuesta no sea lo suficientemente _asertiva_ para ti. :)

Comment: Puedes indicarme en orden cuales serian esos 3 cambios que debo aplicar en el código que agregue en mi pregunta.

Comment: 1. Debes entender tu código y el mio. 2. En tu HTML, agrega una sección dónde apareceran las alertas, el equivalente a mi `div` _alertas_. 3. Crea la función `agregarNuevaAlerta()` a tu código. Realiza los ajustes necesarios para que la alerta se agrege a la sección que has previsto para el efecto. 4. Sustituye cada llamada que tienes a `alert` por la llamada correspondiente a `agregarNuevaAlerta()`.

Comment: El contenido de tu `div ` es diferente a los `input file` que tengo en mi código, es posible adaptar tu ejemplo a los `input file` que yo uso en mi pregunta inicial ?